# Кодировка nestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, кодировка, utf-8, nestjs

Когда я получаю значение от запроса nestJS, то оно возвращает вместо букв "�" такие знаки. Что можно сделать? Как можно поменять кодировку nestJS?

Была замена этого

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  getHello(): string {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

на

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  getHello(): string {
    return 'Привет, мир!';
  }
}
```

Comment: Ну, что-то можно сделать)) Без четкого описания проблемы, только такой ответ можно дать

Comment: Так весь прикол в том, что старт дефолтный (считайте хелло ворлд неста), просто заменил "Hello World" со сгенерированного контроллера на текст с русскими символами. То есть показывать-то и нечего)

Comment: Всё, я добавил описание

Comment: Скорее всего вы сохраняете исходники в какой-то другой кодировке (не UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в `pages/index.js` несколько тегов:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
```

Также можно прописать кодировку в заголовки:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<head> 
  <meta content="text/html;" charset="utf-8" accept-charset="cp1251" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
</head>
```

По памяти. Точно не скажу, была проблема, случайно наткнулся, забил в "meta" и вопрос решился. Стал правильно воспринимать буквально всё.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в кодировке самих файлов